# Summing the difference of all values of one vector that are less than the values in another

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I have the following code below to try and loop through a sequence and select values below these values in a sequence and find the difference from another value. For large datasets, this can take a long time. Is there a way to vectorize something like this without looping through the sequence to improve performance?

```
a <- seq(1, 10, by=0.25)
b <- seq(1, 10, by=1)

c <- vector('list', length(b))

i <- 1
for (n in b){
    c[[i]] <- sum(n - a[n >= a])
    i <- i + 1
}

data.frame(c)
```

I've tried to use data.table to bin the data and find the difference, but cannot figure out how to calculate the difference from every value less than the bin value.

```
library(data.table)

min.n <- 1
max.n <- 10 
a <- data.table(seq(min.n, max.n, by=0.5))
colnames(a) <- 'a'
b <- seq(min.n+1, max.n+1, by=1)

bins <- findInterval(a$a,b)
a[,bins:= bins+2]
a[, diff:= bins - a]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table` using rolling join:

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(a, key="a")
B <- data.table(b, key="b")

A[, c("N", "cs") := .(.I, cumsum(a))]

A[B, on=.(a=b), roll=Inf, N * b - cs]
```

`sum a[a <= n]` can be replaced with cumsum (i.e. `cs` here) and rolling join will find those `a` that are less than `b`. Replace `sum(n - cs)` with a mathematical formula involving the summation symbol so that `sum(constant)` = number of elements in summation * constant.

output:

```
[1]   0.0   2.5   9.0  19.5  34.0  52.5  75.0 101.5 132.0 166.5
```

---

edit: some timings for reference

timing code:

```
set.seed(0L)
library(data.table)
n <- 1e5L
a <- rnorm(n)
b <- rnorm(n/10L)
A <- data.table(a, key="a")
B <- data.table(b, key="b")

mtd0 <- function() A[B, on = .(a <= b), sum(i.b - x.a), by = .EACHI]$V1

mtd1 <- function() {
    A[, c("N", "cs") := .(.I, cumsum(a))]
    A[B, on=.(a=b), roll=Inf, N * b - cs]
}

all.equal(mtd0(), mtd1())
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=1L, mtd0(), mtd1())
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
 mtd0() 2998.208000 2998.208000 2998.208000 2998.208000 2998.208000 2998.208000     1
 mtd1()    7.807637    7.807637    7.807637    7.807637    7.807637    7.807637     1
```

Comment: I used this answer but needed a non-equi join. I used: `fin <-  A[B, on=.(a<b), mult="last", N * b - cs]` and set na values to zero: `fin[is.na(fin)] <- 0`

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table`, this can be achieved by *aggregating in a non-equi join*:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(a)[data.table(b), on = .(a <= b), sum(i.b - x.a), by = .EACHI]$V1
```

> ```
> [1]   0.0   2.5   9.0  19.5  34.0  52.5  75.0 101.5 132.0 166.5
> ```

In a way, it is similar to [MattB's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011140/3817004) but combines the cartesian product `CJ()` and subsetting in the *non-equi join* thereby avoiding to create data which will be filtered out subsequently.

Note that the `x.` prefix is required to pick the `a` column from the first data.table.

---

Alternatively, `sum(i.b - x.a)` can be re-written as `.N * b - sum(x.a)` where the special symbol `.N` denotes the number of rows in a group.

```
data.table(a)[data.table(b), on = .(a <= b), .N * b - sum(x.a), by = .EACHI]$V1
```

> ```
> [1]   0.0   2.5   9.0  19.5  34.0  52.5  75.0 101.5 132.0 166.5
> ```

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution with `findInterval`, which is fast.

```
i <- findInterval(b, a)
sapply(seq_along(i), function(j)sum(b[j] - a[1:i[j]]))
# [1]   0.0   2.5   9.0  19.5  34.0  52.5  75.0 101.5 132.0 166.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(data.table)
a <- seq(1, 10, by=0.25)
b <- seq(1, 10, by=1)

all.combinations <- CJ(a, b)  # Get all possible combinations
all.combinations[b>=a, sum(b-a), by=b]  # Filter for b>=a, then sum the difference for each value of b
```